# what is nginx.config in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, nginx

When i look at magento 2 root then found nginx.conf file.I googled and read many links like

[DEMO HERE](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html)

But still confusion.
My question is why do i configure nginx.conf? What is relation between nginx.config and magento?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx is a **web server** commonly used in Linux web servers, an alternative to Apache if you know what this is. It is also supposed to be quicker than apache and tells the webserver to run and serve http content from **/var/magento/public_html/index.php** if **mydomain.com** is visited for example.

This **nginx.conf** file should only be needed if you are using Nginx rather than Apache and acts similarly to .htaccess files telling the server to run the main index.php, **locking down** certain directories and file types as well as providing options for **compression** and **cache expiration** of certain files and more.

Comment: thanks for response!!! its just server like apache?

Comment: Exactly just an alternative to apache.

Comment: when magento uses nginx server then improve its perfomance?

Comment: Yeah i believe it was designed with the main goal of outperforming apache it uses less memory and in my experience does seem a bit quicker although not hugely. See here there seems to be a question specifically about this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175438/nginx-or-apache-for-magento-2-x

Comment: thanks for help +1.you give me exact information which i want